# Substitution alternating a pattern

Tags: substitute

I have a transcription file that looks like this:

```
[09:46] question

[10:22] answer

[10:25] question

[10:26] answer

[10:27] question
```

and so on...

Now I would like to add an identifier right after the time like this:

```
[09:46] I1: question

[10:22] A1: answer

[10:25] I2: question

[10:26] A2: answer

[10:27] I3: question
```

and so on...

I know I can number each line like this:

```
:let i = 1 | g/]/s//\=printf("] %02d ", i)/ | let i = i+1
```

but how could I alternate the I and A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
let ind=['I', 'A']
let i = 1
let j = 1
g/]/s##\=printf("] %s%02d ", ind[i%len(ind)], j)#|let i+=1|let j=(i%2==1?j+1:j)
```

as mentioned by @JürgenKrämer you can get rid of the second variable `j` and use this:

```
let ind=['I', 'A']
let i = 0
g/]/s##\=printf("] %s%02d ", ind[i%len(ind)], i / len(ind) + 1)#|let i+=1
```

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm!
just one small thing: in order for the sequence to start with the 'I' the ind has to be like this: ind=['A', 'I']

Comment: You can get rid of variable `j` if you start to count from zero and replace `j` with `i / len(ind) + 1` inside the call to `printf()`:
`let ind=['I', 'A']`
`let i = 0`
`g/]/s##\=printf("] %s%02d ", ind[i%len(ind)], i / len(ind) + 1)#|let i+=1`

Comment: thanks @JürgenKrämer cool improvement, let me amend the answer